# Indicator function with equal sign for probability integral

Tags: probability, integral, multinomial-logit, indicator-function

In the beginning of the book Train ([2009](https://eml.berkeley.edu/books/choice2nd/Ch01_p1-8.pdf), p.4) on "Discrete choice methods with simulation" we read:

> Deﬁne an indicator function $I[h(x,ε) = y]$ that takes the value of
> $1$ when the statement in brackets is true and $0$ when the statement is
> false. That is, $I[·] = 1$ if the value of $ε$, combined with $x$,
> induces the agent to choose outcome $y$, and $I[·] = 0$ if the value
> of $ε$, combined with $x$, induces the agent to choose some other
> outcome.

Then the following statement is presented.
$$
P(y | x) = Prob(I[h(x,ε) = y] = 1)\\
= \int I[h(x,ε) = y] f (ε) dε
$$

My question is about ($=$) inside the indicator function under integration.

(In the rest of the book all examples are with *inequality*, because disctrete choice models are built on comparisions of utilitites of different alternatives, like $u_j>u_k$, for all $k\neq j$).

Perhaps, I'm missing something, but I thought that indicator function just trancated the intergral   function (change its bounds), so equal sign in expression must lead such integral to $0$ value. What am I missing? A counterexample is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected value of the indicator fuction $I\{A\}$ (where $A\in\Omega$) is $P(A)$. In this case, the integral of the joint probability indicator function over the whole $\varepsilon$ domain gives us the conditional probability $P(y|x)$ (see more [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812309/conditional-expectation-of-indicator-function)).

For your case, assume $h(x,\epsilon)=x^T\beta+\epsilon$ (which is the first of three possible proofs in your book). Note that it is given that $x$ is observed - meaning that given $x$ and $\epsilon$, we can determine $y$. Moreover, it is clearly stated that $P(y|x)=P(\epsilon~~\text{s.t.}~~h(x,\epsilon)=y)$.

$$\int_{\mathcal{E}}I\{y=h(x,\epsilon)\}f(\epsilon)d\epsilon=\int_{\mathcal{E}}I\{y=x^T\beta+\epsilon\}f(\epsilon)d\epsilon=\int_{\epsilon=y-x^T\beta}{f(\epsilon)}=P(\epsilon=y-x\beta)=\\P(\epsilon~~\text{s.t.}~~x^T\beta+\epsilon=y)=P(y|x)$$

Note that we didn't actually use the realization $h(x,\epsilon)=x^T\beta+\epsilon$.

Comment: can you provide an example with equality, not sets? As an example, let us take linear regression, $\epsilon = y - x\beta$.

Comment: @garej see the added example

Comment: I'm a bit concerned with the following statement: $P(X=a) = \int_a^a f(x)dx = 0$. We can add $1$ inside integral but nothing will change.

Comment: @garej pardon my old habits, I'm used to convert integrals over indicators directly to sums. Although sums and integrals are essentially the same and are usually interchangeable (are you familiar with [Riemman Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum)?), I can see why it's cause confusion, and for your convenience I've changed it to integral. Regarding the integral of the function - that's again integrals as sums and vice versa. We sum over all possible $x$ values for which $x=a$, even if it's a single point. That's where the sum notation makes more sense.

Comment: yes, I undestand that integral is a limit of summation. My confusion stems from the fact that the integral in any point should be effectively $0$. Is $P(y|x) = 0$ in the example? And sum of zeros is zero as well.